# AudioContext issue on Safari

Tags: typescript, angular5, audiocontext, webkitaudiocontext

I'm trying to use AudioContext in my typescript file for an Angular 5 app.  It works great on Chrome, doesn't work on Safari.  Everything I see by googling says to use `window.webkitAudioContext` but that immediately blows up when the typescript compiler runs saying that it doesn't exist on type Window.

```js
let context = new AudioContext();
let source = context.createBufferSource();
context
    .decodeAudioData(event.body)
    .then(x => {
        source.buffer = x;
        source.connect(context.destination);
        source.start(0);
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should extend the `Window` interface and then augment the window object.

Asuming you're using **angular-cli**, add the following to your `typings.d.ts` file:

```
declare interface Window {
  AudioContext: AudioContext;
}
```

Then inside your `polyfills.ts` file you could set the `AudioContext` attribute:

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just cast `window` to `any`:

```
(window as any).AudioContext = (window as any).AudioContext || (window as any).webkitAudioContext;
let context = new AudioContext();
```

Answer (score 2):

I settled on this one-liner:

```
const audioContext: AudioContext = new (window["AudioContext"] || window["webkitAudioContext"])();
```

Comment: This looks simple but unfortunately doesn't compile:
`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.  TS7015`
at the second term in the expression.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the desired properties to the `Window` interface in the global namespace.

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    AudioContext: typeof AudioContext;
    webkitAudioContext: typeof AudioContext;
  }
}

const context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
```